# hadoop distcp fails due to missing yarn log directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, distcp

I am trying to run a distcp command on an EMR cluster:

```
hadoop distcp s3a://... hdfs://host/data/...
```

When I run this, it gives the following error:

```
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/bash: /mnt/yarn/logs/application_1524773139099_0003/container_1524773139099_0003_02_000001/stdout: No such file or directory

Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /bin/bash: /mnt/yarn/logs/application_1524773139099_0003/container_1524773139099_0003_02_000001/stdout: No such file or directory

at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've checked all the nodes in the cluster, and they all have a `/mnt/yarn/logs` directory which I created. What is going on here?

Comment: You will get the same error when the directory permissions are not set to `rwx` for the parent directory

Comment: This is a common exception thrown on your console. Could you please also share the log by running "yarn logs --applicationId application_1524773139099_0003"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user that runs the job have sufficient privileges to create temp directories such as application_******* in the path /mnt/yarn/logs. preferable the hive user and also pull yarn logs for application_1524773139099_0003 to view errors that might explain the actual error.